# Advice to start with Nhibernate on C#: documentation, books and any other good learning resources

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, nhibernate

I need to learn nHibernate from scratch. I'm a experienced .net developer, but I need some advices about using and implementing nHibernate on .NET apps.

Any documentation or book you consider I "must read", or any other advice will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote two entry-level tutorials on my blog:

- [Getting started with NHibernate](http://codethatworks.blogspot.com/2009/11/getting-started-with-nhibernate.html)
- [LINQ to NHibernate](http://codethatworks.blogspot.com/2009/11/linq-to-nhibernate-tutorial.html)
- [Fluent NHibernate Tutorial](http://codethatworks.blogspot.com/2009/12/fluent-nhibernate.html)

I also recommend the "NHibernate in action" book.

Answer (score 3):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135776/best-place-for-nhibernate-documentation) will answer most of what you need. To summarise:

- There's only one book available: [NHibernate in action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1932394923)
- [Ayende's blog](http://ayende.com/Blog/category/510.aspx) has a lot of NHibernate tips (he's one of the main contributors)
- [nhibernate.info](http://nhibernate.info/) has a fair amount of wiki information, docs and blogs
- The [NHibernate tag on Delicious](http://delicious.com/tag/nhibernate) has a lot of sites
- And obviously Googling 'NHibernate' or 'NHibernate blog'

Answer (score 3):

Watching the screencasts on http://www.summerofnhibernate.com/ do provide a nice introduction to Nhibernate.

Comment: I'm just gonna "go ahead and" +1 this answer

Comment: Haha, Kent.  That drives me bonkers and so many webcast authors do it.   "Go Ahead" tourette's is catching ;)

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Mastering NHibernate](http://www.tekpub.com/preview/nhibernate) series on Tekpub.

Answer (score 1):

[NHibernate In Action](http://www.manning.com/kuate/) is a very good book.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this to be pretty good:

https://web.archive.org/web/20090831053827/http://blogs.hibernatingrhinos.com/nhibernate/archive/2008/04/01/your-first-nhibernate-based-application.aspx